# Calculate vector forces on object being affected by wind

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors

I am wondering how you calculate the vector forces of the wind on an object? The information I have is the bearing direction of the wind and the speed of the wind. So how do I calculate the *x* and *y* vector forces of the wind as shown in the diagram below? Also I do realise that using trig I can do a straight calculation but that only works out the speed not the force.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wind does not impart a 'force' on the object. The object does not 'feel' the wind (as long as it's not in contact with the ground). What actually happens is that the object moves concurrently with the wind in the same direction and with the same speed, in addition to the object's own velocity. So you have the object's velocity and the wind velocity; add them up and you get a net velocity, which is the true direction of travel.

From what is given, the angle that the velocity makes with the vertical is
$$\theta=360^{\circ}-\text{Wind Bearing Angle}$$

The horizontal and vertical components of velocity are 
$$\cos (\theta)=\frac{W_y}{W}$$
$$\sin (\theta)=\frac{W_x}{W}$$
where $W$ is the net wind velocity.

You add the components of the wind speed to the object's speed to get the net velocity
$$V_{x}=W_x+O_x$$
$$V_y=W_y+O_y$$

Comment: Cheers Greg, that was my suspicion but wasn't entirely sure. It helped alot :)

Comment: As far as I can tell, this answer contradicts itself.  If the object travels with the same velocity as the wind (relative to the ground say) then it's completely unclear why $O_x$ and $O_y$ in your last two equations are not automatically zero.  Moreover, it's absolutely not the case that flying objects always fly with the same velocity as wind (think for example of an airplane flying against a headwind).  Wind *does* exert forces on objects unless those objects are in fact flying with precisely the same velocity as the wind, but this rarely happens.

Comment: @joshphysics Do you know a better equation for this then?

Comment: @Nicholas There is no way to solve this problem as it is written.  The force of the air on a given object depends on the relative velocity of the object and the wind (among other things like its drag coefficient) neither of which have been specified.  Is this the precise way the problem was initially stated?

Comment: @joshphysics Yes there is, I am using this for a physics simulation for programming. I do have the information of the velocity of the object and have the information for the velocity of the wind. Any other information needed can be gotten if needed :)

Comment: @joshphysics please see this explanation: http://www.physicsclassroom.com/mmedia/vectors/plane.cfm In fact, pilots always carry a special tool (the E-6B calculator) that allows them to compute the wind correction angle (WCA) by simple vector addition, among other things: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_triangle

Comment: @Nicholas Your question as it is written is "how you calculate the vector forces of the wind on an object?"  This question cannot be answered with the data given for reasons I outlined in my first comment.  However, if this is not your question, and if you are simply looking for the velocity of the object relative to the ground, then, provided you are given the objects velocity relative to the wind *and* the wind's velocity relative to the ground, then I certainly agree that this is simply a vector addition problem.  As far as I can tell, you did not give these in the statement of the problem.

Comment: @joshphysics The idea is that there is no force acting on the plane due to the wind, because the air and the plane are all drifting concurrently at the wind velocity. However, there is a very real force of the air on the plane, *due to the plane's motion through the air*, which is the drag force. This is like asking what is the force of the current on a boat traveling from one side of a river to the other. The boat does not experience a force from the speed of the current, but from it's own motion through the water. Josh, perhaps you've mistaken wind for 'relative wind'?